# Wrong timestamp in systemd log

Tags: systemd, logs, timestamps, systemd-journald

I read systemd log of my home server using `journalctl` and I've noticed that the timestamp of the log is totally out of order.

Here are some logs from my server using `journalctl -o short-iso --since=yesterday` :

```
2015-06-17T06:00:22+0900 alarm smbd[463]: [2015/06/17 06:00:22.911093,  0] ../source3/printing/print_standard.c:69(std_pcap_cache_reload)
2015-06-17T06:00:22+0900 alarm smbd[463]: Unable to open printcap file /etc/printcap for read!
2015-06-17T06:13:23+0900 alarm smbd[463]: [2015/06/17 06:13:23.161572,  0] ../source3/printing/print_standard.c:69(std_pcap_cache_reload)
2015-06-17T06:13:23+0900 alarm smbd[463]: Unable to open printcap file /etc/printcap for read!
-- Reboot --
1970-01-01T09:00:06+0900 alarm systemd-journal[179]: Runtime journal is using 8.0M (max allowed 87.5M, trying to leave 131.2M free of 867.2M available <E2><86><92> current limit 87.5M).
-- Reboot --
1970-01-01T09:00:06+0900 alarm systemd-journal[177]: Permanent journal is using 336.0M (max allowed 2.9G, trying to leave 420.5M free of 25.2G available <E2><86><92> current limit 2.9G).
1970-01-01T09:00:06+0900 alarm systemd-journal[177]: Time spent on flushing to /var is 5.440ms for 2 entries.
1970-01-01T09:00:06+0900 alarm kernel: Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
1970-01-01T09:00:06+0900 alarm kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset

....

1970-01-01T09:00:21+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Started Update is Completed.
1970-01-01T09:00:21+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
1970-01-01T09:00:21+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
1970-01-01T09:00:21+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
-- Reboot --
1970-01-01T09:00:05+0900 alarm systemd-timesyncd[187]: System clock time unset or jumped backwards, restoring from recorded timestamp: Thu 2014-07-03 18:46:22 UTC
2014-07-04T03:46:22+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Time has been changed
2014-07-04T03:46:22+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
2014-07-04T03:46:22+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Starting System Time Synchronized.
2014-07-04T03:46:22+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Reached target System Time Synchronized.

...

2014-07-04T03:50:45+0900 alarm dhcpcd[324]: eth0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1
2014-07-04T03:50:45+0900 alarm systemd-timesyncd[187]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
2014-07-04T03:50:45+0900 alarm systemd-timesyncd[187]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
2014-07-04T03:50:46+0900 alarm systemd-timesyncd[187]: Using NTP server 216.239.32.15:123 (time4.google.com).
2014-08-30T12:21:54+0900 alarm systemd[255]: Time has been changed
2014-08-30T12:21:54+0900 alarm systemd-timesyncd[187]: interval/delta/delay/jitter/drift 32s/+4955468.150s/0.322s/0.000s/+0ppm
2014-08-30T12:21:54+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Time has been changed
2014-08-30T12:21:54+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Starting Verify integrity of password and group files...

...

2014-08-30T14:12:57+0900 alarm systemd-timesyncd[185]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
2014-08-30T14:12:57+0900 alarm systemd-timesyncd[185]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
2014-08-30T14:13:27+0900 alarm systemd-timesyncd[185]: Using NTP server 216.239.36.15:123 (time3.google.com).
2014-09-05T20:47:48+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Time has been changed
2014-09-05T20:47:48+0900 alarm systemd-timesyncd[185]: interval/delta/delay/jitter/drift 32s/+542061.386s/0.335s/0.000s/+0ppm
2014-09-05T20:48:21+0900 alarm systemd-timesyncd[185]: interval/delta/delay/jitter/drift 64s/+0.002s/0.338s/0.001s/+0ppm
2014-09-05T20:49:35+0900 alarm systemd-timesyncd[185]: Timed out waiting for reply from 216.239.36.15:123 (time3.google.com).

....

2014-09-06T22:48:10+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Starting Shutdown.
2014-09-06T22:48:10+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
2014-09-06T22:48:10+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Starting Final Step.
2014-09-06T22:48:10+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
2014-09-06T22:48:10+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Starting Power-Off...
2014-09-06T22:48:10+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Shutting down.
2014-09-06T22:48:10+0900 alarm systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
2014-09-06T22:48:10+0900 alarm systemd-journal[167]: Journal stopped
-- Reboot --
1970-01-01T09:00:04+0900 alarm systemd-journal[169]: Runtime journal is using 8.0M (max allowed 87.5M, trying to leave 131.2M free of 867.2M available <E2><86><92> current limit 87.5M).
1970-01-01T09:00:04+0900 alarm systemd-journal[169]: Runtime journal is using 8.0M (max allowed 87.5M, trying to leave 131.2M free of 867.2M available <E2><86><92> current limit 87.5M).
1970-01-01T09:00:04+0900 alarm kernel: Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0

...
```

As you can see, there are lots of discontinuation and jump back and forward of timestamp. This is only a snippet and there are much more such points.

I've checked my time setting but I couldn't find anything wrong:

```
$ timedatectl status
      Local time: Thu 2015-06-18 16:46:44 KST
  Universal time: Thu 2015-06-18 07:46:44 UTC
        RTC time: Thu 2015-06-18 07:46:44
       Time zone: Asia/Seoul (KST, +0900)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

How can I fix this mess?

My environment:

- Device: [Wandboard Quad](http://wandboard.org/details)(it's a single board computer)
- OS: Arch Linux ARM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that your systems clock is not functioning, probably because of the battery not, or  no longer providing enough current to keep the clock going during restart. (If the clock chip where bad, you should get a different error, ntpd should notice).

That is why you reboot in 1970 when the "Unix era" starts.

When `ntpd` starts it hears from the rest of the world that the clock was not working and sets the time & date accordingly

```
1970-01-01T09:00:21+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
1970-01-01T09:00:21+0900 alarm systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
-- Reboot --
1970-01-01T09:00:05+0900 alarm systemd-timesyncd[187]: System clock time unset or jumped backwards, restoring from recorded timestamp: Thu 2014-07-03 18:46:22 UTC
```

You should be able to save the date on shutdown and at least continue with that value instead of 1970, but it is better to replace the clock's battery.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using a single board computer for my server so-called Wandboard Quad. I don't see any battery on device. Maybe, I have to change the external power supply, then. Thank you.

Comment: @xylosper That machine doesn't seem to [have a timer at all}(http://www.digikey.com/~/media/Images/Product%20Highlights/W/Wandboard/Solo%20-%20Dual%20-%20Quad%20Development%20Boards/wandboard-wbsolo-wbquad-wbdual-large-block-diagram.jpg?la=en) that would mean it cannot retain the time between reboots. Saving the time before shutdown and restoring it with `ntpdate` or something similar would at least set the time to something closer to the current time.

Comment: @xylosper Maybe [this](http://xyne.archlinux.ca/projects/timedatectl-restorer/) can help you out.

Comment: Thank you. I've just rebooted my device but I cannot see any discontinuation in log: Jun 18 17:51:11 alarm systemd-journal[171]: Journal stopped
-- Reboot --
Jun 18 17:51:26 alarm systemd-journal[161]: Runtime journal ...<omit>

Comment: Oops, sorry. I've just tried cold reset and yeah, it resets timestamp. Thank you. I'll try your suggestion.

Jun 18 17:53:26 alarm systemd[1]: Starting Update DDNS for dnszi.com...
-- Reboot --
Jan 01 09:00:08 alarm systemd-timesyncd[258]: System clock time unset or jumped backwards, restoring from recorded timestamp: Thu 2015-06-18 17:53:45 KST
Jun 18 17:53:45 alarm systemd[1]: Time has been changed

Comment: If that link works out, please let me know with a short comment.

Comment: Btw, there's still mystery. Since NTP is enabled, it should be automatically adjusted, isn't it? Futhermore, as you can see from the log, wrong time is reported by NTP(this happened yesterday, that is Jun 17 in localtime): '2014-07-04T03:50:46+0900 alarm systemd-timesyncd[187]: Using NTP server 216.239.32.15:123 (time4.google.com).
2014-08-30T12:21:54+0900 alarm systemd[255]: Time has been changed'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24945/discussion-between-anthon-and-xylosper).